# Undefined variable immediately after declaring it?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, canvas, undefined

I'm creating a Game Loop in javascript using var/function classes (for want of a better word). However, I have this strange error where javascript states that a variable is undefined immediately after declaring it...

> main.js:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: game is not defined

In this case, that line is;

```
game.context.beginPath();
```

However, this line is not called until the `init` function calls `game.balls.push(/../)`; Haven't I already declared 'game' by this point, or am I missing something?

Here is my code (Apologies for the length, hopefully most of it can be ignored):

```
/*
 Keep This: #217398
 */

var Game = function () {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.balls = [];

    var that = this;

    this.start = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(that.update);
    };
    this.update = function () {
        that.draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(that.update);
    };
    this.draw = function () {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        for(var x = 0; x < this.balls.length; x++){
            this.balls[x].draw();
        }
    };

    this.start();
};

var Ball = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = 2;
    this.dy = 2;
    this.ballRadius = 10;

    this.draw = function(){
        game.context.beginPath();
        game.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        game.context.fillStyle = 'black';
        game.context.fill();
        game.context.closePath();

        this.x += this.dx;
        this.y += this.dy;

        if(this.x + this.dx > game.canvas.width - this.ballRadius || this.x + this.dx < this.ballRadius)
            this.dx = -this.dx;
        if(this.y + this.dy > game.canvas.height - this.ballRadius || this.y + this.dy < this.ballRadius)
            this.dy = -this.dy;
    };
};

function init(){
    var game = new Game();

    game.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
        game.balls.push(new Ball(100, 100));
    });
}
```

Comment: The variable `game` is local to the `init()` function and not visible inside that `draw()` function. You can add a parameter to the `Ball()` constructor so that you can pass in a reference to `game`.

Comment: Thank you! If you could post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `Ball()` so that you can explicitly pass in a reference to the `Game()` instance:

```
var Ball = function (game, x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // etc
};
```

Then:

```
function init(){
    var game = new Game();

    game.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
        game.balls.push(new Ball(game, 100, 100));
    });
}
```

Now the `Ball()` code has access to a reference to the `Game()` instance you created.

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared the `game` variable using the `var` keyword within the `init` function, it will be scoped to the `init` function (and not available to other functions not nested within `init`).

```
function init(){
    var game = new Game(); // will be scoped to init

    game.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
        game.balls.push(new Ball(100, 100));
    });
}
```

So, one option would be to declare `game` outside of init which would broaden it's scope, or you could declare it as an instance variable to `Ball`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `game` is scoped to the `init` function in which it is created. This means that it can't be accessed outside of this function. There are many work arounds for this. You could make game a global variable, or pass it to the `Ball` constructor.

Another possible solution is having a global namespace which keeps track of these important objects.

```
var SomeNamespace= {};

SomeNamespace.game= new Game();
```

What I personally like to do is run my simple games in closures.

```
(function(){

    var game = new Game();

    var ball = new Ball(); // Ball now has access to game.
})()
```

Sidenote, you can create globally scoped variables within functions, by omitting the `var` keyword, but it's considered a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for this - I've seen closures before, but haven't really wrapped my head around them yet. I'll give them another look!

Comment: Your assertion that `Ball()` has access to `game` would only be true if all the `Ball()` code were moved inside that enclosing function.

Comment: @Pointy So for Ball to see game, would ball be returned in the enclosure or game?

Comment: @Lewis well if the entirety of the `Ball()` constructor function were moved inside that initialization function, then it'd work.